# LINQ with joining on less and more (solved in SQL)

Tags: c#, sql, linq, null, left-join

I have a problem with writing a LINQ query but the SQL query is no problem. In the example below I want to find whitch questions have no answers and please note that question and answers can be "reused" . Also note that a question with a certain QuestionID can only be active once at a time - no overlapping times. SQL code to generate example:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QuestionHistory](
    [QuestionHistoryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Question] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [AskedTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LatestResponseTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_QuestionHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [QuestionHistoryID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,        
 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[QuestionHistory] ON
INSERT [dbo].[QuestionHistory] ([QuestionHistoryID], [QuestionID], [Question],    
[AskedTime], [LatestResponseTime], [UserId]) VALUES (2, 1, N'A',
CAST(0x0000A20900000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A20A00000000 AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[QuestionHistory] ([QuestionHistoryID], [QuestionID], [Question],
[AskedTime], [LatestResponseTime], [UserId]) VALUES (3, 1, N'A',
CAST(0x0000A20B00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A20E00000000 AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[QuestionHistory] ([QuestionHistoryID], [QuestionID], [Question],
[AskedTime], [LatestResponseTime], [UserId]) VALUES (4, 1, N'A',
CAST(0x0000A1F200000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A21200000000 AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[QuestionHistory] ([QuestionHistoryID], [QuestionID], [Question],
[AskedTime], [LatestResponseTime], [UserId]) VALUES (5, 2, N'B',
CAST(0x0000A20B00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A21100000000 AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[QuestionHistory] ([QuestionHistoryID], [QuestionID], [Question],
[AskedTime], [LatestResponseTime], [UserId]) VALUES (6, 2, N'B',
CAST(0x0000A21400000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A21E00000000 AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[QuestionHistory] ([QuestionHistoryID], [QuestionID], [Question],
[AskedTime], [LatestResponseTime], [UserId]) VALUES (7, 3, N'C',
CAST(0x0000A21500000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A21600000000 AS DateTime), 1)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[QuestionHistory] OFF
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AnswerHistory]    Script Date: 08/28/2013 09:49:26
 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AnswerHistory](
    [AnswerHistoryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AnswerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [QuestionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Answer] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ResponseTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_AnswerHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[AnswerHistoryID] ASC

)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,    
 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[AnswerHistory] ON
INSERT [dbo].[AnswerHistory] ([AnswerHistoryID], [AnswerID], [QuestionID], [Answer],
[ResponseTime], [UserId]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, N'AA', CAST(0x0000A20D00000000 AS DateTime),
 2)
INSERT [dbo].[AnswerHistory] ([AnswerHistoryID], [AnswerID], [QuestionID], [Answer],
 [ResponseTime], [UserId]) VALUES (2, 1, 1, N'AA', CAST(0x0000A21200000000 AS     DateTime), 2)
INSERT [dbo].[AnswerHistory] ([AnswerHistoryID], [AnswerID], [QuestionID], [Answer], [ResponseTime], [UserId]) VALUES (4, 2, 2, N'AB', CAST(0x0000A21000000000 AS DateTime), 2)
INSERT [dbo].[AnswerHistory] ([AnswerHistoryID], [AnswerID], [QuestionID], [Answer], [ResponseTime], [UserId]) VALUES (5, 3, 2, N'AB', CAST(0x0000A21000000000 AS DateTime), 3)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[AnswerHistory] OFF
```

The sql statement that generates the correct answer is following:

```
SELECT * FROM [example].[dbo].[QuestionHistory] qh 
LEFT JOIN  [example].[dbo].[AnswerHistory] ah 
ON qh.questionID=ah.questionID 
AND ah.[ResponseTime]<qh.LatestResponseTime 
AND ah.[responseTime]>qh.AskedTime 
WHERE ah.answerhistoryid IS NULL
```

The correct answer is four records... these questions have no answers during fourtimes when they are active.

Now to my question.. **is this really possible to do in LINQ** or do I have to do a stored procedure and return the data that way? If its possible how would the LINQ look like? 
(my gut answer is no) :(

Comment: What's the question? I don't understand which part of the SQL query you think you can't write in LINQ...

Comment: The less and more part of comparing time in the left join and is there no workaround?

Answer (score 3):

it is prossible to do in LINQ:

```
   var query= from qh in db.QuestionHistory
              join ah in db.AnswerHistory
                           .Where(x=> x.ResponseTime < qh.LatestResponseTime 
                                   && x.responseTime > qh.AskedTime
                                   && !x.answerhistoryid.HasValue) 
              on qh.questionID equals ah.questionID into leftGroup
              from ah in leftGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select qh;
```

Comment: The `&& !x.answerhistoryid.HasValue` should go after the `from ah in` probably. It's a check to take only the rows where the left join has failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the QuestionHistory-AnswerHistory relation defined in your EntityFramework, it should be something like this:

```
var query= from qh in db.QuestionHistory
           where !qh.AnswerHistory.Any(x => 
                 x.ResponseTime < qh.LatestResponseTime && 
                 x.responseTime > qh.AskedTime)
           select qh
```

equivalent to:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM [example].[dbo].[QuestionHistory] qh 
    WHERE NOT EXIST (
        SELECT 1 FROM [example].[dbo].[AnswerHistory] ah 
            WHERE qh.questionID=ah.questionID AND 
                  ah.[ResponseTime]<qh.LatestResponseTime AND 
                  ah.[responseTime]>qh.AskedTime
    )
```

Comment: I get that AnswerHistory is not accessible from QuestionHistory. My guess is that is because they are connected on a many to many relationship(QuestionID) Any suggestions how to correct that? Must i breakup the tables to create a external table to handle it?

Comment: @JerkerPihl ORMs normally have problems with "non simple" relations like this one not simply based on primary-secondary key. I haven't ever needed to do it.

Comment: I guess you used LINQ to Entity and not LINQ to SQL?

Comment: @JerkerPihl I used both, but normally my relations are direct father-child or in general their join are pure equijoins.